# Once Shapefile is imported to Matlab, How to use longitude and latitude data from the created structure

Tags: excel, matlab, import, coordinates, shapefile

I created a shapefie from a portal item in Arc GIS. So, on Matlab, I have this map, which shows the polygons outlined within NYC:
[MapNYC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCPZ2.jpg)

The shapefile I have is called "Sewershed.shp".
In Matlab, I type in:

`shaperead('Sewershed');`

Then, I get a 17x1 structure
[17x1 Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW97y.jpg)

So, the heading, "Bounding Box" are the longitude and latitude boundaries that define the Sewersheds (under heading "SewerShed")
The polygons in the map I showed above are the outlines of the sewer shed.

Now, I have an Excel spreadsheet that lists items as defined by longitude latitudes. I need to identify which Sewer Shed each item belongs to.
[Excel Spreadsheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vis6L.jpg)

I'd appreciate any help with this!

Josephina

Answer (score 0):

assuming your boundingbox record has `[x0,y0, x1,y1]` where `x0-x1` is the range of the longitude and `y0-y1` is the range of your latitude. If you have a new coordinate `newpt=[long1, lat1]`, you just need to compare `long1` with `x0-x1` and `lat1` with `y0-y1` and find the records that they belong to.

here is my sample test code

```
mydata(1).BoundingBox=[1,2,5,7]
mydata(2).BoundingBox=[2,3,6,9];
mydata(3).BoundingBox=[7,1,8,20];
bbx=cell2mat({mydata(:).BoundingBox}')

newpt=[4,3]
find(newpt(1)>=bbx(:,1) & newpt(1)<=bbx(:,3) & newpt(2)>=bbx(:,2) & newpt(2)<=bbx(:,4))
```

Comment: Hi FangQ. Thank you for your answer. I understand your sample code. I feel perhaps my question was misdirected. I suppose having set boundaries would work if the sewer shed shapes were rectangles, as opposed to irregularly shaped polygons. In addition, it seems that the sample code requires manual input. I am looking for a way to call the points from the excel spreadsheet and match them to the polygon from the shapefile.

Comment: In that case, you replace the four comparisons by a function called inpolygon.

Comment: ```shaperead('Sewer')

mydata(1).inpolygon=['26th Ward']
mydata(2).inpolygon=['Bowery Bay'];
mydata(3).inpolygon=['Coney Island'];
mydata(4).inpolygon=['Hunts Point'];
mydata(5).inpolygon=['JAM']
mydata(6).inpolygon=['Newtown Creek'];
mydata(7).inpolygon=['North River'];
mydata(8).inpolygon=['Oakwood Beach'];
mydata(9).inpolygon=['Owls Head']
mydata(10).inpolygon=['Port Richmond'];
mydata(11).inpolygon=['Red Hook'];

bbx=cell2mat({mydata(:).inpolygon}')

newpt=[-73.92178148,40.58778492]```

Comment: no. that's not how it works. run `help inpolygon` to see how to call this function. Basically, you need to get the polygon's node list (sequential, last is assumed to be connected to the 1st), assuming you can get those polygon nodes from your town names. Then, to test whether your coordinates belong to this polygon, you call `inpolygon`, it returns you 1 if inside, 0 if outside. For each town/polygon, you can test all coordinate list using a single `inpolygon` call. Click on this link to see examples: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it